# Макрос в Excel не работает как надо

Tags: excel, макросы

Есть EXCEL таблица - есть 2 рабочих листа, внутри этих листов есть макрос который заставляет при вбитии одного значения в первом листе добавлять его во второй лист. Суть в том что этот макрос не работает и я не могу найти причину. Я залила файл EXCEL на яндекс диск и выделила необходимые поля куда вбиваются и откуда выводятся данные серым цветом. Мне нужна помощь с тем что бы настроить макрос так что бы он работал - вот ссылка на файл который находится на яндекс диске: https://yadi.sk/i/XYqqDEfcO_CcNg помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

> я не могу найти причину

Пжалста...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. А не могли бы вы дать мне вашу версию рабочую уже в экселе? Просто я не понимаю что с этим и реплей делать( пожалуйста

Comment: Рабочую? да мне и в голову не пришло отлаживать ВАШУ программу. Вы просили ошибку? одну я нашёл и указал. А дальше пилите сами... PS. Эта переменная вообще не нужна: `If vbYes = MsgBox(...) Then ...`.

Comment: Ну может вы отладите? Потому что я убираю то на что вы указали все ровно не пашет*(

Comment: Вы что-то путаете - SO никогда не был биржей фриланса.

Comment: Ну я поняла, просто я подумала что вы сможете... В любом случае спасибо Вам за потраченное время.