# Правка макроса в Excel таблице

Tags: excel

Есть EXCEL таблица - есть 2 рабочих листа, внутри этих листов есть макрос который заставляет при вбитии одного значения в первом листе добавлять его во второй лист. Суть в том что этот макрос не работает и я не могу найти причину. Я залила файл EXCEL на яндекс диск и выделила необходимые поля куда вбиваются и откуда выводятся данные серым цветом. Мне нужна помощь с тем что бы настроить макрос так что бы он работал - вот ссылка на файл который находится на яндекс диске: https://yadi.sk/i/XYqqDEfcO_CcNg помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дубликат вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1060631/229437 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1060669/229437

Comment: Я прошу прощения конечно но задача не решена я выцепляю информацию по крупицам потому что никто не хочет сделать мне работающий эксель - мне жаль что вам доставляет это неудобства.